# Solution of a second order PDE with the only condition that the solution of its Sturm-Liouville DE is in terms of Sine and Cosine

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following PDE

```
equation= k^2*WW[r, \[Theta]] + Derivative[0, 2][WW][r, \[Theta]]/r^2 + Derivative[1, 0][WW][r, \[Theta]]/r + Derivative[2, 0][WW][r, \[Theta]] == 0
```

But Mathematica can not solve it:

```
DSolve[equation,WW,{r,\[Theta]}]
```

The result is the same expression as the above input.

The only condition I have is the dependence in [theta] should be in terms of Sine and Cosine and I do not have any other boundary condition.

Can anyone help me how can I solve this Helmholtz PDE?

Comment: Your code does not work. syntax errors. Can you try to post the InputForm?

Comment: The correct syntax is: `equation = 
  k^2 WW[r, \[Theta]] + Derivative[0, 2][WW][r, \[Theta]]/r^2 + 
    Derivative[1, 0][WW][r, \[Theta]]/r + 
    Derivative[2, 0][WW][r, \[Theta]] == 0;` or: `equation = 
  k^2 WW[r, \[Theta]] + D[WW[r, \[Theta]], {\[Theta], 2}]/r^2 + 
    D[WW[r, \[Theta]], r]/r + D[WW[r, \[Theta]], {r, 2}] == 0;`  However, are you sure that a closed form of the solution exists?

Comment: I edited the equation. Previously I copied the equation as plain text but this time I used 'InputForm[...]' @Nasser

Comment: The solution does exists. The sturm-Liouville DE is in terms of Sine and Cosine and the other DE  is the Bessel function. @DanielHuber

Comment: What about initial and boundary conditions?

Comment: The only condition I have is that after separation of variables and taking the expressions of r and \[theta] to each side, the constant equal to each expression is chosen such that the Sturm-Liouville DE becomes in terms of Sine and Cosine.@DanielHuber